# I cannot properly read Southbound commands through Orion to MQTT devices

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to send commands in the Southbound direction following this flow:

[image]

The commands supported by the devices are provisioned as follows:

```
    "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
            "cbroker":     "'"http://orion:$ORION_PORT"'",
            "entity_type": "Agv",
            "transport": "MQTT",
            "resource": "",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_Alarm",
                    "name": "AGV_Alarm",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": {
                        "data": "metadata_for_AGV_Alarm"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_Event",
                    "name": "AGV_Event",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": {
                        "data": "metadata_for_AGV_Event"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

The request to send the command in the Southbound direction is made through the Orion Context Broker:

```
curl -iX PATCH \
  'http://orion:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Agv:001/attrs' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "AGV_Event": {
      "type" : "command",
      "value": "152"
  }
}'
```

To simulate actuators the following tool is used which is listening for commands via MQTT:

```
docker run -it --rm --name mqtt-subscriber --network fiware_default efrecon/mqtt-client sub -h mosquitto -t "/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/cmd"
```

I can receive only a part of the payload of the command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-85-246:~/FiwareDockerDevMode$ docker run -it --rm --name mqtt-subscriber --network fiware_default efrecon/mqtt-client sub -h mosquitto -t "/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/cmd"
{"AGV_Event":""}
{"AGV_Event":""}
{"AGV_Event":""}
```

In the temporary MongoDB, the command status appears as PENDING

```
AGV_Event_status: {
            type: 'commandStatus',
            creDate: 1669583822.6813245,
            modDate: 1669584130.4993052,
            value: 'PENDING',
            mdNames: [
                'TimeInstant'
            ],
            md: {
                TimeInstant: {
                    type: 'DateTime',
                    value: 1669584130.495
                }
            }
        },
        AGV_Event_info: {
            type: 'commandResult',
            creDate: 1669583822.6813245,
            modDate: 1669583822.6813245,
            value: ' ',
            mdNames: []
        },
```

**Update**

If, on the other hand, I send the command according to the structure it has in MongoDB:

```
curl -iX PATCH \
  'http://orion:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Agv:001/attrs' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
    "AGV_Event_info": {
    "type": "commandResult",
    "value": "200"
    },
   "AGV_Event_status": {
    "type": "commandStatus",
    "value": "OK"
   }
  }'
```

Now, nothing is received in the actuator simulator:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-85-246:~/FiwareDockerDevMode$ docker run -it --rm --name mqtt-subscriber --network fiware_default efrecon/mqtt-client sub -h mosquitto -t "/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/cmd"
```

However, the temporary MongoDB is updated properly:

```
        AGV_Event_status: {
            type: 'commandStatus',
            creDate: 1669731581.9883916,
            modDate: 1669733857.6557434,
            value: 'OK',
            mdNames: []
        },
        AGV_Event_info: {
            type: 'commandResult',
            creDate: 1669731581.9883916,
            modDate: 1669733857.6557305,
            value: '200',
            mdNames: []
        },
```

The official documentation of the [IoTAgent-JSON](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/iot-agent-json/index.html) suggests that when commands are sent in the Southbound direction the actuator will send a response, which would make sense considering that my actuators are dummies.

Any suggestions on how to receive all the information sent through the Orion Context Broker?

[Update]

*Provision devices:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  curl commands to reload the data from the previous tutorial
#
#

set -e

printf "⏳ Provisioning IoT devices "


#
# Create a service groups for all UltraLight IoT devices
#

curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST \
  "http://iot-agent:$IOTA_NORTH_PORT/iot/devices" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device_id": "agv001",
      "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Agv:001",
      "entity_type": "Agv",
      "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
      "transport": "MQTT",
      "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
      "static_attributes": [
        {
          "name": "refStore",
          "type": "Relationship",
          "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
  ]
}'

echo -e " \033[1;32mdone\033[0m"
```

*Provision services:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  curl commands to reload the data from the previous tutorial
#
#

set -e

printf "⏳ Provisioning IoT services "


#
# Create a service groups for all UltraLight IoT devices
#

curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST \
  "http://iot-agent:$IOTA_NORTH_PORT/iot/services" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
    "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
            "cbroker":     "'"http://orion:$ORION_PORT"'",
            "entity_type": "Agv",
            "transport": "MQTT",
            "resource": "",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_Alarm",
                    "name": "AGV_Alarm",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_Event",
                    "name": "AGV_Event",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_Th",
                    "name": "AGV_Th",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_Th"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_X",
                    "name": "AGV_X",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_X"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_Y",
                    "name": "AGV_Y",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_Y"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_battery",
                    "name": "AGV_battery",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_battery"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_error_id",
                    "name": "AGV_error_id",
                    "type": "WORD",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_error_id"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AVG_extended_status",
                    "name": "AVG_extended_status",
                    "type": "STRING[256]",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AVG_extended_status"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_location_score",
                    "name": "AGV_location_score",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_location_score"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_connect",
                    "name": "AGV_connect",
                    "type": "BOOL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_connect"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_connected",
                    "name": "AGV_connected",
                    "type": "BOOL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_connected"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_go_point_X",
                    "name": "AGV_go_point_X",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_go_point_X"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_go_point_Y",
                    "name": "AGV_go_point_Y",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_go_point_Y"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_go_point_Th",
                    "name": "AGV_go_point_Th",
                    "type": "REAL",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_go_point_Th"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_go_goal",
                    "name": "AGV_go_goal",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_go_goal"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "object_id": "AGV_IP",
                    "name": "AGV_IP",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "metadata": {
                        "unitCode": {
                            "type": "Text",
                            "value": "metadata_for_AGV_IP"
                        }
                    }
                 },
                { 
                    "name": "AGV_Cmd", 
                    "type": "command", 
                    "value": "" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'

echo -e " \033[1;32mdone\033[0m"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command is incorrectly provisioned. For testing, try something like `name` only:

```json
"commands": [
        { "name": "ring", "type": "command" }
],
```

For each command rather than adding `object_id` or `value`.

`object_id`  is only required if there is a different naming convention between the Context Broker data model and the MQTT topic.

The PATCH for `XXX_status` and `XXX_info` is not relevant here. This request is made by the. IoT Agent itself once it receives an `cmdExe` topic from MQTT. Since the MQTT transport is asynchronous, the status will remain at `PENDING` unless the device (or a dummy topic on MQTT) has explicitly returned a status update.

Comment: Thanks, I have simplified the command to:
 "commands": [
                {
                    "name": "AGV_Alarm",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": {
                        "data": "125"
                    }
                }
            ]                                                                                                                                                                                   However, the issue persists. In any case, I need to send not only the command but also an associated value.

Comment: I have also tested without "type": "command" with the same result:                                       "commands": [ { "name": "AGV_Alarm", "value": { "data": "metadata_for_AGV_Th"}}]

Comment: Have you tried adding the apiKey into the provisioning? `"transport": "MQTT",
      "apikey": "4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
      "commands": [
        { "name": "ring", "type": "command" }
       ],```

Comment: Yes, I had added the apikey. For instance "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov",
            "cbroker":     "'"http://orion:$ORION_PORT"'",
            "entity_type": "Agv",
            "transport": "MQTT",
            "resource": "",
            "commands": [{
                    "name": "AGV_Alarm",
                    "type": "command",
                    "value": ""
                }], "attributes": [{ 
                    "name": "AGV_Ring", 
                    "type": "command", 
                    "value": "" 
                }]

Comment: As you can see, in the previous comment. I have tried to use the command also as a type within an attribute. I have tried to follow the documentation: https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/iot-agent/index.html#southbound-traffic-commands

Comment: Not SERVICES , in the DEVICE

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more information on how I provision both devices and services.